# how to get the type from a object value based on a variable

Tags: typescript

I have the following type:

```
type Core = {
  a: string
  b: number
}
```

I would like to be able to get the type of one of the entities for use elsewhere.

pseudocode:

```
const c: <the type of Core.a> = 'hello'
```

basically I want a type that takes a variable (`a` in this case) that then returns the value from the above object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want [indexed access types, aka lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).  If `T` is a type, and `K` is the type of one of its keys (or a union of such types), then `T[K]` is the type of the property of that key (or a union of such properties).  In your case, `T` is `Core` and `K` is the string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"a"`:

```
const c: Core["a"] = 'hello'; // okay
```

Note that lookup types only support bracket notation, `T["a"]`; you can't use dot notation like `T.a`, even when the key is a string literal.  (Dot notation would cause a potential name collision with namespaces/modules; if you had a namespace named `T` that exports a type named `a` then `T.a` is the name of that type.)

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gJ2gXigbwFBSgQwFxQDOwCAlgHYDmWUARgeQK4C2tECGAvhhgMZzliUXgXhIA2gCIckgLpRUAcgAWEADZq4igNxA)