# Use field of a class member in another class member's generic defition

Tags: typescript, roblox

I'm making an ECS and this is the code I have for the System class, which will hold behavior:

```js
type Trigger<Components extends Component, Query = Components['type'][]> = (...components: ComponentSet<Components, Query>) => void;

interface Query<Components extends Component> {
    withAll: Components['type'][]
}

abstract class System<Components extends Component> {
    query: Query<Components>;
    
    constructor(query: Query<Components>) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    abstract onFrame: Trigger<Components, this.query.withAll>;
}
```

ComponentSet is a type that takes an array of component types (["Health", "Inventory"]) and transforms it into its actual component values ({health: number}, {activeSlot: number}). What is strange is that the above does not work, I get a syntax error on the last line, the one declaring an abstract member onFrame. But when I change this.query.withAll to a literal, such as:

```
abstract onFrame: Trigger<Components, ["Health"]>;
```

Then TypeScript throws no issue. Why is it that a literal works fine but a variable access does not work, despite both having the same type? Is there a way to work around this or solve this?

FYI Components['type'] is a string, the Component interface I've defined elsewhere ensures this.

Comment: What error do you get? Could you show a playground with all the code necessary to reproduce this?

Comment: Types and values have completely different namespaces, and you seem to be confusing them.  In `Trigger<Components, ["Health"]>`, `["Health"]` is a type, *not* a value; it's a one-element one-element [tuple](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) type whose first (and only) element is the string [literal type](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"Health"`.  On the other hand, if you wrote `const x = ["Health"]`, the `["Health"]` would be a value, not a type.

Comment: Contrast: if you write `Trigger<Components, this.query.withAll>`, that `this.query.withAll` needs to be a type, but it isn't one.  Dotted delimiters in types represent modules/namespaces, so in order for `this.query.withAll` to be a type there would have to be something like `namespace This {namespace query { export type withAll = ...`, but you probably can't have a namespace named `this`.  And no matter what, there's essentially no chance that the type `this.query.withAll` would be the type of the value named `this.query.withAll`.  The namespaces are different.

Comment: "Is there a way to work around this or solve this?" can only be answered if you provide a [mre] suitable for others to test for themselves.  You *might* be able to write `this["query"]["withAll"]` but without something I can paste into a standalone IDE, then I'm ‍♂️

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60085933/how-to-get-the-type-from-a-object-value-based-on-a-variable